# App ported to iOS 7 now requests microphone access

Tags: ios, avplayer

We've almost finished porting our app to iOS7, but we've ran into an issue that AVPlayer defaults playback on the iPhone to the receiver (quiet speaker) instead of regular loud speaker. A solution for that appears to be using

```
AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback ...];
```

this, however, on iOS7 pops up a dialog requesting microphone permission. Why? How can I avoid  this, as the app doesn't record anything? We're using AVPlayer for playback and also have background audio permission.

Comment: would a better title for this question be "audio playback on iOS 7 now requests microphone access"?

Comment: I have posted this question 1 month ago and still no answer :/ ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916044/using-a-bluetooth-sound-device-in-ios7-without-microphone-permissions

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to override output rote of Audio session? I've had similar problem on iOS 6 when sound was played on loudspeaker on iPod but on phone speaker on iPhone.

```
UInt32 audioRoute = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof(UInt32), &audioRouteOverride);
```

Comment: It says that the function `AudioSessionSetProperty` is deprecated in iOS7

Comment: but it still asks for the microphone permission on iOS7 and iPhone 4, so this isn't the cause

Comment: My bad, didn't see that changed. Maybe this could help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807157/how-do-i-route-audio-to-speaker-without-using-audiosessionsetproperty

Comment: I'm using almost exactly that, the sound does actually go to the loudspeaker, but the app is asking for microphone permission (that is the point of this question)