# Access to microphone for recording via code, iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

In my App am using AVAudioRecorder for recording. There is no problem regarding the recording. When I play my app for the first time, the problem is that an alertview pop ups, regarding  allow/dis allow the microphone to be used.

I want to have

1) control over this default alertview, so that my recording and timer (a label that is used to show the seconds, audio recorded) starts only when I click on Allow microphone,

OR

2) need to set microphones available for the app, so that It doesn't prompt the alertview asking to allow/dis allow microphone.

I searched internet, stackoverflow, but didnt get any thing related to this post. 
Read some posts, but they were regarding displaying the status, that microphone is available for app or not, which is not of that much use for me.

Comment: What's with all the bold?

Comment: This is a system wide behavior and cannot be changed. The user has to be asked if your app can use the microphone the first time.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato
cannot we have access to that alert view window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John mentioned in the comments it is default behaviour for the app to ask for permission to use the microphone and this cannot be changed. However you can however check to see if permission has been granted.

You should probably have a look through this question as it explains how to check and see if access has been granted to use the microphone. You can then start your recording once permission has been granted.

[Detect microphone permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625738/ios-7-microphone-input-permission-refused-how-to-detect)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i need something else to control my NsTimer. For the time being am using isRecording, which will give me true/false, and according to which I will handle my NsTimer, and recording related stuff

Comment: code, didnt actually solved the issue, but some how I used that code in different manner, and my app is working