# AVAudiorecorder status, not getbale

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

```
AVAudioSession *session= [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];  
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
```

am using **AVAudiorecorder**, when the second line executes, I get following on my console

> [0x3bc9218c] Microphone input permission refused - will record only
>   silence

Is there any method where I can get bool which tells that 2nd line returns true/false.

I posted related question to this, but didnt get any success, below is that link

[Access to microphone for recording via code, iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838704/access-to-microphone-for-recording-via-code-ios)