# Show custom alert like Shazam app for getting permission on AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, ios7

I have already refereed the Stackoverflow Link :- [How to check for microphone access at time of launch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142630/how-to-check-for-microphone-access-at-time-of-launch)

But I want to show alert in full screen for getting permission as shown in Shazam app.

App Site :- https://support.shazam.com/entries/26560426-Microphone-access-now-required-iOS7-

App Link :- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shazam/id284993459?mt=8

I want to show alert like this. Can anyone help me on this issue?

Code that i have tried so far :-

```
-(BOOL)requestforpermisssion
{

     __block BOOL result=NO;


    #ifndef __IPHONE_7_0
       typedef void (^PermissionBlock)(BOOL granted);
    #endif


        PermissionBlock permissionBlock = ^(BOOL granted)
        {
            if (granted)
            {
                [self setupRecording];
                result = YES;
            }
            else
            {
                // Warn no access to microphone
                result = NO;
            }
        };

        // iOS7+



            if([[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] respondsToSelector:@selector(requestRecordPermission:)])
            {
                [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] performSelector:@selector(requestRecordPermission:)
                                                      withObject:permissionBlock];
            }



  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Shazam app, the first screen is simply a `UIView` with some text and buttons.

[image]

In the buttons(*Don't Allow* and *OK*), they are calling the block with value `YES` and `NO`.

If the user click *Don't Allow* button, a system generated alert will appear.

[image]

You can change the description of system generated alert by adding the string value in attribute `Privacy - Microphone Usage Description`. Add this attribute in your *Info.plist* file.

In your `Permission` block

```
PermissionBlock permissionBlock = ^(BOOL granted)
        {
            if (granted)
            {
                [self setupRecording];
                result = YES;
            }
            else
            {
                // Warn no access to microphone
                result = NO;
            }
        };
```

Comment: i agree with you morpheus but i want to customise system generated alert like shaman application. you will find link of app in above post. i request you to please check app and please give your feedback on it.

Comment: @Leena You can customize the message by using `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`.

Comment: In Info.plist file add the attribute `Privacy - Microphone Usage Description` as string with custom message as a value.

Comment: i agree with you we can change message but i wan to display first alert like shaman thats my main issue. i request you to please don't downnvote because my friend post question on behalf of me. my ask question feature is blocked.

Comment: morpheus i wan to show that first screen with 2 buttons. i want to show that custom alert view.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51878/discussion-between-morpheus-and-anjan)