# How to check if user disabled microphone in Settings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

In my app I'm recording audio with `AVAudioRecorder` and can't seem to find any solution to detect if user disabled usage of microphone for the app in Settings. When the microphone is disabled an instance of `AVAudioRecorder` created successfully, methods `prepareToRecord` and `record` return `YES` , no delegate methods detect an error. Everything looks fine except that nothing is recorded eventually. So is there any chance to detect that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18839838/2982796

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect microphone input permission refused in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625738/how-to-detect-microphone-input-permission-refused-in-ios-7)